# DatePicker doesn't work well on real device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-datepicker

I use `DatePicker` in Xamarin.Forms.

On UWP and virtual Android device, it works well.
This is a screenshot of virtual device.

[image]

But on real android device, it doesn't work on.

[image]

Why does this problem occur?

Version of my real device is Android11, so I changed target version. However, the problem doesn't solve.

Is the function not compatible with Android 11?

And then, A switch button doesn't display well too.

~ Add ~

On Android11 virtual device, The function works well.

This is my code

MainPage.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async void newpage(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new addPage());
    }
 }
```

addPage(excerpt)

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="7,5,5,5"
                          >
                <Label Text="           開始日時"
                       FontSize="17"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="startTimePicker"
                            Format="yyyy/MM/dd"
                            Date="2021/01/30"
                            HorizontalOptions="End" />
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: From what you have shared, it seems like your phone doesn't have the English language support needed. It's definitely not an issue with your code.
Also, you might be able to check the application output to see if it gives you any details

Comment: Is the DatePicker only available in English?

Comment: No but you likely have to add a language locale to make it appear in the language you want

Comment: Like this?

"CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");"

Comment: @roku I don't have android 11 real device, but I test at android 8.1 real device, it works fine, so can you test at another real device?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I don't have another device:-(
Is default language of your phone English? or another?

Comment: XF 5.0.0.2196 (SR6) includes the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution!

Dark theme is caused this problem, so turning off the function resolve this.

Or Add this code onCreate in MainActivity.cs

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

Comment: this disables dark mode at all which people may not like. Have you tried my workaround?

Comment: I will try it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is [known for a while](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9033) and is fixed in [a PR](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/14591), that is part of Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0 SR6 ( 5.0.0.2196 ).

So update Xamarin.Forms to get the fix.